# SQL 1999/2003 v/s Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I'm new to postgresql. I wanted to know, how we resolve 1 to many and many to many relationships in postgresql considering that we want to make our schema pure object-relational rather than conventional RDBMS.

For instance, in sql 1999 we have multisets, REF, un-nesting etc., what is it's replacement in postgresql.

```
CREATE TYPE PersonType AS (
Name CHAR(50),
Id CHAR(9),
PRIMARY KEY (Id)
)
CREATE TYPE BuyerType UNDER PersonType AS (
Transactions REF( TransactionType)
MULTISET SCOPE Transaction
)
CREATE TYPE SellerType UNDER PersonType AS (
Transactions REF( TransactionType)
MULTISET SCOPE Transaction
)
CREATE TYPE TransactionType AS (
Id CHAR(10),
Date date,
Buyer REF( BuyerType) SCOPE Buyer,
Seller REF( SellerType) SCOPE Seller
)
CREATE TABLE Person of PersonType;
CREATE TABLE Buyer of BuyerType;
CREATE TABLE Seller of SellerType;
CREATE TABLE Transaction of TransactionType;
```

Now, we can run this query

```
SELECT S.Id, S.Name, count(DISTINCT T->Buyer->Id)
FROM Seller S, UNNEST(S.Transactions) T
GROUP BY S.Id, S.Name
```

Consider the above example for designing a schema in SQL 1999/2003
How would to create similar schema when it comes to postgresql. Can we write such formulated queries in postgresql.

Comment: Can you give some examples. I really don't understand what exactly it is you are trying to do. Or which problem you are trying to solve. Postgres as `unnest()` it has arrays even arrays of record types (is that what you mean with multisets?). Not sure what REF is about.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Please see the updated question.

Comment: What does this `REF` thing do?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I think it means that `ByerType.Transactions is of type TransactionType`. Not sure why the OP wants to travel that path, AFAIK this was introduced by many vendors but I have not heard of anyone using it. Db2 documentation here:   https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.structypes.doc/doc/t0006609.html

Comment: And what does `MULTISET SCOPE Transaction` do?

Comment: FWIW, I don't think the PRIMARY KEY should be declared in the type. The following validated ok at at:  https://developer.mimer.com/services/sql-validator-99/  `CREATE TYPE PersonType AS (
Name CHAR(50),
Id CHAR(9)
) FINAL;

CREATE TYPE BuyerType UNDER PersonType AS (
Transactions REF( TransactionType)
) FINAL;

CREATE TABLE Person of PersonType;`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I guess its to describe the 1:n relation that a buyer / seller can be part in many transactions as opposed to the 1:1 relation for a single transaction of having 1 buyer , 1 seller

Comment: Please see the above sql example. I'm asking if it is possible to design such a schema and then run some query similar to that in sql 1999/2003 in postgresql.

Comment: In Postgres object types can't inherit from each other (unlike tables). Your type definitions also contain circular references that can't easily be resolved, so I don't see how this could be converted to Postgres